# Why are my nodes not showing up in a Panel?

Tags: 7, nodes, panels

I am experiencing something strange: the nodes in my Panels are not showing up anymore. When adding content to my Panels, I can select *Existing node*, pick the right node title (e.g. *Test article*) and save the Panel without any problem:

[image: Node in Panel]

But, afterwards, the node is not printed on the according Panel page:

[image: Panel page]

However, everything worked fine in the past and a quick test on a fresh website shows that there is no bug in the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module. Also, other entities like Views are displayed just fine. I have already checked some things that might cause the problem:

- The node template at **Structure/Panels** is enabled, but that doesn't matter: disabling it does not change anything.
- The node in the Panel does neither have a style, nor any visibility rules.
- My custom modules do not interfere with the printing of nodes or panels.
- Clearing the caches doesn't change anything.
- All users have permission to view published nodes; visiting the node's full page works fine:

[image: Node's full page]

Do you have any idea what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Just a thought, click that setting gear which is shown in your first image at right hand side. And under style, check which style is being selected. It should be No style, in normal case.

Comment: @CodeNext: Thanks for your suggestion, but *No style* it is...

Comment: Sometimes changing the jQuery version affects The UI of modules like Panels and Views

Comment: What have you done recently? Maybe it can be a hint.

Comment: Backup your DB and try re-installing Panels, and make sure you have the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem of non-displayed Panes can be caused by quite a lot of things, it can also take quite a lot of time to find a solution (2 days in my case). It turned out that I had overwritten `panels-pane--node.php.tpl` in my custom theme and that I accidently put an `if` statement around the whole code, which only returned `TRUE` for one specific node. Woops...

In order to make the searching process a bit easier for future users who have a similar problem, I will sum up some stuff to try underneath.

### Maybe it's a theming thing

If you have a custom theme, your first reflex should probably be to take a look at it. (That being said, my reflexes aren't that good apparently.) First, use a tool like Firebug to inspect your Panel and make sure that the Pane isn't printed. Something like a lost `visibility: hidden;` can easily be solved in your CSS files. If your Pane just isn't there, maybe there is something wrong with one of your templates. Take a look at the templates that start with `panels-pane`.

### Maybe it's a Panels thing

Take a look at the Pane's settings in your Panel. As CodeNext suggested in the comments above, check that the active style is *No Style*. In other cases, there can be a problem with (the CSS of) that style. Also, make sure that you didn't set a visibility rule that hides the Pane for you.

### Maybe it's a clashing modules thing

P Magunia suggested that the jQuery version can affect the proper working of Panels. If you installed [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update), you can temporarily deactivate this module to see whether something changes. In my case, nothing happened. Also, install the latest versions of all modules on your website. Maybe the Panels module clashes with another outdated module or is outdated itself (see  No Sssweat's comment).

Taking Jimmy Ko's remark into consideration, I reinstalled an old backup of my website, where the problem did not arise, and updated all installed modules. Since the problem was still there, I could convince myself that the hidden Pane was not related to any module. Yet another reason for backing up your website's (WAMP) folder and database.

### PS: Maybe it's an alien thing

If none of the above hints worked, no error messages are shown, Google lets you down, and you have been clicking and typing around for days, probably some aliens hacked your website and are making fun of you. Beware, they are potentially dangerous. Never lose your temper...

Comment: Love this answer